# StreetAddress not showing in Profile Card Properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have added the **StreetAddress** to Profile Card Properties as per the following command:

```
POST /beta/organization/{organizationId}/settings/profileCardProperties
```

and confirmed the setting with a corresponding GET, as described at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationsettings-post-profilecardproperties?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http.

However, despite waiting many days, the Office 365 Profile Card is not showing the StreetAddress as a property. We have the values for StreetAddress populated in user profiles.

Could this be checked please, as we have different offices with similar floor numbers, so having the StreetAddress in the profile card is quite essential?

Comment: Hi @Kapil, DId you get the success message after you ran the query,as i checked it does not support application permissions, it only works for delegated , for reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationsettings-post-profilecardproperties?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue with permissions, have you tried to check the permissions you are using whether they are delegated or Application permissions.

This only works for delegated permissions:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organizationsettings-post-profilecardproperties?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions